# How to get day of week in SparkSQL?

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to select all record recorded at Sunday through SparkSQL.
I have the following try but in vain.

```
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE DATEPART(WEEKDAY, create_time) = 0
SELECT * FROM mytable WHERE strftime("%w", create_time) = 0
```

How to get day of week in SparkSQL?

Comment: do you just need the current day of the week in int form?

Comment: What do you mean 'int form'?  I would like to query all records created on Sunday.  **create_time** is a field in table **mytable** where log the create time of a record.

Comment: Ok I get what you're saying, should be the same as in normal sql, if not you can query it as a a normal RDD, an sql table in spark is generally accessible as a case class

Comment: But the query I state above does not work in SparkSQL query.  The context seems not implemented yet.  I would like to know whether there is some other way to achieve my goal.

Answer (score 40):

SPARK 1.5.0 has a `date_format` function that accepts a format as an argument. This format returns a name of a week day from a timestamp:

`select date_format(my_timestamp, 'EEEE') from ....`

**Result: e.g. 'Tuesday'**

Comment: It's not clear this answers the question, as the question wants to select records for a specific day of the week, not format the result as a day of the week. Can `date_format` be used in the `WHERE` clause? If so, modify your answer to demonstrate that.

Comment: Seems like you can learn more about the formatting string [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

Answer (score 8):

If the create_time is in the format of UTC, you can use the following to filter out specific days in SparkSQL. I used Spark 1.6.1:

```
select id,  date_format(from_unixtime(created_utc), 'EEEE') from testTable where date_format(from_unixtime(created_utc), 'EEEE') == "Wednesday"
```

If you specify 'EEEE', the day of the week is spelled out completely. You can use 'E' to specify the shortened version, e.g. Wed. 
You can find more info here:
http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 7):

Here's an example that shows the output from the different options.  Suppose you have this DataFrame.

```
+----------+
| some_date|
+----------+
|2021-01-10|
|2021-01-11|
|2021-01-12|
|2021-01-13|
|2021-01-14|
|2021-01-15|
|2021-01-16|
|      null|
+----------+
```

Here are the results of using the `dayofweek`, `date_format`, and `dayOfWeekStr` (from [spark-daria](https://github.com/MrPowers/spark-daria)) functions.

```scala
import com.github.mrpowers.spark.daria.sql.functions._

df
  .withColumn("dayofweek", dayofweek(col("some_date")))
  .withColumn("date_format", date_format(col("some_date"), "EEEE"))
  .withColumn("dayOfWeekStr", dayOfWeekStr(col("dayofweek")))
  .show()
```

```
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
| some_date|dayofweek|date_format|dayOfWeekStr|
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
|2021-01-10|        1|     Sunday|         Sun|
|2021-01-11|        2|     Monday|         Mon|
|2021-01-12|        3|    Tuesday|         Tue|
|2021-01-13|        4|  Wednesday|         Wed|
|2021-01-14|        5|   Thursday|         Thu|
|2021-01-15|        6|     Friday|         Fri|
|2021-01-16|        7|   Saturday|         Sat|
|      null|     null|       null|        null|
+----------+---------+-----------+------------+
```

The `daysofweek` output is best for date addition with `date_add` or `date_sub`, as described in [this post](https://mungingdata.com/apache-spark/week-end-start-dayofweek-next-day/).

The `date_format` solution is best for customizing the dates for a given format (e.g. for a human readable deliverable).

Some date functions, like `next_day` take a day in string form as argument, and that's when `dayOfWeekStr` comes in handy.

Comment: hey you manage mungingdata - great resource, keep it up!

Answer (score 4):

This works for me:

```
spark.sql("select dayofweek(time) as dow from some_table")
```

Where `time` needs to be in date format