# Day of the week pyspark

Tags: python, function, datetime, pyspark

I'm trying to get the day of the week from a given date in pyspark could anyone help me ?

```
dt = dt.withColumn("week_day_number", date_format(col("TRANSACTION_DATE"), "u"))
```

Comment: did you have a look at [How to get the weekday from day of month using pyspark](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38928919/10197418)?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm trying to get the day of the week from a given date ..

See [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.weekday).

(Once you have a `datetime` instance just call `weekday()`)

*Monday is 0 and Sunday is 6*

```
import datetime

print(datetime.datetime.today().weekday())
```