# Column of day of the week using a datetime column in SparklyR

Tags: r, dplyr, sparklyr

I am doing some analysis on a large dataset and thus am using sparkly R to hold the data. One of the columns in my spark data frame is a datetime column, for example 2015-05-01 13:40:47

I am looking to add a new column to my spark data frame with the day of the week that this date corresponds to. I have tried so many things and have no luck as I am completely new to SparkR.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006607/how-to-get-day-of-week-in-sparksql

Answer (score 0):

In `sparklyr` you'd use the `date_format` function within `mutate`. Translating (part of) @jayrhythium's answer so you can compare:

```
library(sparklyr)
library(dplyr)

sc <- spark_connect(master = "local")
df <- tibble(id = 1:3,
             date_time = c('2020-07-01 12:01:19.000',
                           '2020-06-24 12:01:19.000',
                           '2020-08-16 16:44:55.406'))

df %>%
  copy_to(sc, ., "df", overwrite = TRUE) %>%
  mutate(date_timestamp = from_utc_timestamp(timestamp(date_time), "UTC"),
         week_day_full = date_format(date_timestamp, "E"))
```

(I also drew on [code from a sparklyr issue](https://github.com/sparklyr/sparklyr/issues/2140) for this example)

This code works for me with Spark 3.3.0.

Answer (score -1):

This is how you would do it in Pyspark. It should be very similar with SparkR.

```
    from pyspark.sql import functions as F

    df = spark.createDataFrame(
        [
            (1,'2020-07-01 12:01:19.000'),
            (2,'2020-06-24 12:01:19.000'),
            (3,'2020-08-16 16:44:55.406')
           
        ], 
        ['id','date_timestamp']
    )
    df.show()
    /*
    +---+-----------------------+
    |id |date_timestamp         |
    +---+-----------------------+
    |1  |2020-07-01 12:01:19.000|
    |2  |2020-06-24 12:01:19.000|
    |3  |2020-08-16 16:44:55.406|
    +---+-----------------------+
    */

    df.withColumn("date_timestamp", F.col("date_timestamp").cast('timestamp')
    ).withColumn("week_day_number", F.date_format(F.col("date_timestamp"), "u")
    ).withColumn("week_day_full", F.date_format(F.col("date_timestamp"), "EEEE")
    ).show()
    /*
    +---+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
    |id |date_timestamp         |week_day_number|week_day_full|
    +---+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
    |1  |2020-07-01 12:01:19    |3              |Wednesday    |
    |2  |2020-06-24 12:01:19    |3              |Wednesday    |
    |3  |2020-08-16 16:44:55.406|7              |Sunday       |
    +---+-----------------------+---------------+-------------+
    */
```